# IOS Weird behaviuor for background push notifications when app is killed

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I think I've read every possible documentation and every possible answer over the web and Still can't make this work:

1. Using Firebase cloud functions to send to APNS server
2. there are 4 devices: two are up to date with 13.3.1 (XR and SX Max), one with 13.1 (6s) and one with 12 (6) ios installed
3. Sending push notification reaches all phones when they are in the foreground or in the background
4. Sending push notification reaches all phones but the one with the ios 12, when app is killed but still connected to the power and have network
5. After disconnecting from power for a period of time or loosing network connection, Even if plugging in the phone again and regaining network the XS max stopped receiving notifications but the XR and the 6S still receiving them. (**didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: not firing!**)

I've tried every trick and every suggestion given anywhere.

Using Swift 4.2 from development right now and supported SDK for this project is IOS 10 (Company didn't raise to to Swift 5 and IOS 12/13)

App Code:
The subscription happens always (working fine)

In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "theTopic") { error in
    print("Subscribed to LocationWakeNotify topic")
}

let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert]) { (granted, error) in }
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Server code:

```
let message = {
  topic: data.topic,
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        "content-available" : 1
      },
      "content-id" : 1
    },
    headers: {
      "apns-push-type" : "background",
      "apns-priority" : "5"
    }
  }
};
```

I tried with content-available : true and it is the same.

I've tried with and without the headers and this happens only when app is killed and with silent notifications, if i send content (title/body) then there is 100% delivery to all devices but i need it to be silent notification.

It seems to me that when i disconnect power or network or something (i just cant figure this out) some devices loose listener?!? I will mention that i cant find any deference in the settings in the XR that is always working and the XS Max that looses connectivity.

The weirder issue is that it seems like in all devices location changes are firing (locationManage:didUpdateLocations:) but the notification delegate is not being fired. So it is not even App is being disconnected form the OS. And the notifications are working as in some devices they are working all the time and in other not... very weird.

10x

Comment: Hello @Erez, did you manage to resolve the issue? We're experiencing the same for iOS 12 as well. It seems that, we are forced to handle the case differently based on OS used in device. :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you Registered For Notifications? 
you can try with this code in `AppDelegate` and call this func in `didFinishLaunch`

````
private func registerRemoteNotifications(for application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        // Notifications
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: { _, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
    ```
````

Comment: Yes, did the of course, Otherwise i wouldn't have received the notifications in the ones i'm getting them, Edited my question, The issue is that some phone are working great and some stops receiving the notification for some reason, 10x

Comment: can you check certificates with FCM Token through Firebase? 
try to update Firebase Pod